# creating a tree function using helper functions

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree, treenode

For class we were asked to create a binary search tree. The small issue is that our helper functions aren't part of the header class, and so when I try and use the helper functions I created to add to the tree or to traverse the tree it always gives me a segmentation fault, or the wrong output. The code for the header class is just creating the structure class for the Nodes

```
struct MovieNode{
    int ranking;
    string title;
    int year;
    float rating;

    MovieNode* left = NULL;
    MovieNode* right = NULL;

    MovieNode(int rank, string t, int y, float r) {
        title = t;
        ranking = rank;
        year = y;
        rating = r;
    }
};
```

The source code file contains all of the classes from the header file, as well as helper functions which I created in order to help with the task.

```
#include "MovieTree.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// MovieNode: node struct that will be stored in the MovieTree BST

MovieTree::MovieTree() {
  this -> root = NULL;
}

MovieTree::~MovieTree() {
  // delete every node and then set the root to NULL
}
```

I personally don't know how destructors work. Mine always get segmentation faults.

```
// helper function to printMovieInventory()
void inorderTraverse(MovieNode* node) {
  inorderTraverse(node -> left);
  cout << "Movie: " << node -> title << " " << node -> rating << endl;
  inorderTraverse(node -> right);
}

void MovieTree::printMovieInventory() {
   // using inorder traversal

   if (root == NULL) {
     cout << "Tree is Empty. Cannot print" << endl;
   }
   else if (root != NULL) {
     inorderTraverse(root);
   }
}
```

This function uses in order traversal to print out all of the movies along with their rating. What actually happens is a segmentation fault.

```
// helper function to addMovieNode()
void insert(MovieNode* root, int ranking, string title, int year, float rating) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = new MovieNode(ranking, title, year, rating);
  }
  if (title < root -> title) {
    insert(root -> left, ranking, title, year, rating);
  }
  else if (title > root -> title) {
    insert(root -> right, ranking, title, year, rating);
  }
}

void MovieTree::addMovieNode(int ranking, string title, int year, float rating) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = new MovieNode(ranking, title, year, rating);
  }
  else if (root != NULL) {
    insert(root, ranking, title, year, rating);
  }
}
```

This function was the one that confused me the most. Most functions I've seen to insert a new node into a tree require a pointer to a node `Node* node` and then the data that will go into the node. So whenever I run this function, it only inserts the first node (the root), and then nothing else gets inserted into the tree.

```
// helper function to findMovie()
MovieNode* compare(string title, MovieNode* root) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  else {
    if (title.compare(root -> title) < 0) {
      compare(title, root -> left);
    }
    else if (title.compare(root -> title) > 0) {
      compare(title, root -> right);
    }
    else if (title.compare(root -> title) == 0) {
      return root;
    }
  }
}

void MovieTree::findMovie(string title) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    cout << "Movie not found." << endl;
  }
  else {
    MovieNode* foundMovie = compare(title, root);

    if (foundMovie == NULL) {
      cout << "Movie not found." << endl;
    }
    else {
      cout << "Movie Info:" << endl;
      cout << "==================" << endl;
      cout << "Ranking:" << foundMovie -> ranking << endl;
      cout << "Title  :" << foundMovie -> title << endl;
      cout << "Year   :" << foundMovie -> year << endl;
      cout << "rating :" << foundMovie -> rating << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

This function is comparing the titles of the movies and then traversing the tree to find the movie that matches it. If it isn't in the tree then it return that the movie couldn't be found. This one keeps outputting weird values in the rating, year, and ranking. Even if the movie isn't found, it outputs some random values for it.

```
// helper functino to queryMovies()
void preorderTraverse(MovieNode* node, int rating, int year) {
  if (node -> rating >= rating && node -> year < year) {
    cout << node -> title << "(" << node -> year << ") " << node -> rating << endl;
  }
  else {
    preorderTraverse(node -> left, rating, year);
    preorderTraverse(node -> right, rating, year);
  }
}

void MovieTree::queryMovies(float rating, int year) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    cout << "Tree is Empty. Cannot query Movies" << endl;
  }
  else if (root != NULL) {
    cout << "Movies that came out after " << year << " with rating at least " << rating << endl;
    preorderTraverse(root, rating, year);
  }
}
```

This function is similar to `findMovie()` except it compares the year and rating and then prints out all of the movies that came out after the year, and had a rating greater than or equal to the rating. It does this in no particular order, so I traversed the tree using preorder. It gets a segmentation fault as well.

```
// helper function to averageRating()
int average(MovieNode* node, int sum) {
  sum += node -> rating;

  average(node -> left, sum);
  average(node -> right, sum);


  return sum;
}

void MovieTree::averageRating() {
  if (root == NULL) {
    cout << "Average rating:0.0" << endl;
  }
  else if (root != NULL) {
    int avg = 0;
    avg += average(root, avg);

    cout << "Average rating:" << avg << endl;
  }
}
```

Like the name says, this function adds up all the ratings and divides by how many nodes there are to get the average. This one I'm still working on, so I know it's full of bugs.

```
// helper function to printLevelNodes()
void getLevel(MovieNode* node, int level) {
  if (node != NULL) {
    if (level == 0) {
      cout << "Movie: " << node -> title << " " << node -> rating << endl;
    }
    else if (level != 0) {
      getLevel(node -> left, level - 1);
      getLevel(node -> right, level - 1);
    }
  }

}

// helper function to printLevelNodes()
int maxLevel(MovieNode* node) {
  if (node == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    int leftD = maxLevel(node -> left);
    int rightD = maxLevel(node -> right);

    if (leftD > rightD) {
      return (leftD + 1);
    }
    else {
      return (rightD + 1);
    }

  }
}

void MovieTree::printLevelNodes(int level) {
  int max = maxLevel(root);

  if (level <= max) {
    getLevel(root, level);
  }
}
```

Funny enough, the last function is the only function that works. This doesn't make sense to me because I modeled the helper functions after one another, but some of them just don't seem to work. Is there a way to access the tree from the helper functions even though they're not part of the header file? If there isn't, then how are some of the helper function working, but not others?

Answer (score 0):

There are some silly mistakes in **inorder function** followed by **insert function**. :( Follow me down here:

> This function uses in order traversal to print out all of the movies along with their rating. What actually happens is a segmentation fault.

The reason of segmentation fault is you are checking left and right part **even if it contains NULL**. Where, you should check only left part when left part is acutally exist and it is same for right part also.

change:

```
void inorderTraverse(MovieNode* node) {
 if(node -> left)
    inorderTraverse(node -> left);

 cout << "Movie: " << node -> title << " " << node -> rating << endl;

 if(node -> right)
    inorderTraverse(node -> right);
}
```

> This function was the one that confused me the most. Most functions I've seen to insert a new node into a tree require a pointer to a node Node* node and then the data that will go into the node. So whenever I run this function, it only inserts the first node (the root), and then nothing else gets inserted into the tree.

Since you want to add nodes at the exact position, you have to go to the position first. Then only you can add nodes [or reference at the correct position].

change:

```
MovieNode * insert(MovieNode* root, int ranking, string title, int year, float rating) 
{
 if (root == NULL) {
   return new MovieNode(ranking, title, year, rating);
 }
 if (title < root -> title) {
  root->left = insert(root -> left, ranking, title, year, rating);
 }
 else if (title > root -> title) {
   root-> right = insert(root -> right, ranking, title, year, rating);
 }

 return root;
}

void MovieTree::addMovieNode(int ranking, string title, int year, float rating) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = new MovieNode(ranking, title, year, rating);
  }
  else if (root != NULL) {
    root = insert(root, ranking, title, year, rating);
  }
}
```

NOW, hope everything is OKAY! ping here, if you get stuck or get wrong output anywhere.